# FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support on Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, fuse

I'm trying an app that require to enable a cloud based file system to my device. For this I've to have FUSE support in my Android device . I'm using Android version 4.4.2 on a Asus tablet. However I searched a lot but couldn't find some satisfactory answer to ensure that whether Android support Fuse. Thus I have few question as below ,

1.According to my search result When I run cat /proc/filesystems on an app (Terminal Emulator for Android) that provides Linux terminal I found the result of cat shows "Fuse" there . Is that mean my system support Fuse interface to allow install an user space file system ?

2. I also found in some forum either Fuse should come as built inside kernel or it should be as fuse.ko module under /system/lib/module . But my system doesn't contain fuse.ko hence does it mean I don't have fuse ?

In short, my question is how to ensure FUSE on android device ? I'm a beginner in Android programming so any help is much appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Modern versions of Android utilize Fuse internally, for example to implement the emulated External Storage.

However, Android is locked down and so neither 3rd party applications, not in most cases the human user, are allowed to add additional filesystems.

For **stock Android** the only choice will be to implement file-system-like operations within application code, creating a private API that replicates basic file operations, without actually using any files.  Anywhere in the code you are writing or porting and need to access one of the remote "files", you would substitute your API for the actual file one.  A good example of this would be Android assets - they look a lot like files and have many similar operations, but at runtime they actually are not files but an Android-unique storage mechanism.

Anything else would require modifying Android away from stock configuration (ie, root hacks, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To check what your version of Android on your device supports, download a terminal emulator, and from the command line, run the following snippet of commands minus the parentheses...

"cat /proc/filesystems"

And scroll through the results looking for fuse.  This will be a list of supported filesystems weather it be compiled into the kernel or loadable module.